# Can't type url src ampersand in XSP Editor

Tags: xml, xpages

The xPage XSP editor does not allow me to type `&` in the src url

```
<xp:script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=1234&test=1" />
```

or

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=1234&test=1" />
```

I can ofcourse change the url to `&amp;` but then google does not accept the url

any ideas?

[image: src]?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The xPage XSP editor does not allow me to type `&` in the src url

`&` means "Start of character reference". If you want to include one as data you must use the character reference for it: `&amp;`.

> I can of course change the url to `&amp;` but then google does not accept the url

The XML parser must decode it back to `&` when it converts from XML to a data structure. By the time it gets to Google, it shouldn't be `&amp;` any more.

Comment: so, what does this mean? when I look in html source the url still have &amp;

Comment: `&` has the same meaning (and implications) in HTML as it does in XML. You are presumably parsing the XML (turning the `&amp;` into `&`), generating HTML from the data (turning `&` into `&amp;`) — so of course the HTML *source* will show `&amp;`) — and then the browser will parse it back to `&` again and use that when it makes the HTTP request.

Answer (score 4):

don't use script, use xp:scriptBlock for output scripts, like this:

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
    <xp:this.src><![CDATA[
        http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=1234&test=1
    ]]></xp:this.src>
</xp:scriptBlock>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, actually got it working the script src way also, not sure what I did wrong before :-)

Comment: Thomas, If you are using an attribute outside the basic XML characters (where & is a special character), you should use CDATA. Normally Designer converts attributes to CDATA when you write a SSJS for instance. Sometimes, you have to do it manually :)

Answer (score 3):

If the property panels/events view is used to enter a value then Domino Designer should convert the property to a CData if it detects a special XML character in the property value.
If you enter the value manually into source designer will not modify the attribute value.

```
<xp:scriptBlock>
<xp:this.src><![CDATA[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=1234&test=1]]></xp:this.src></xp:scriptBlock>
```

is the correct way of entering xml with special characters